Viber is not working
I installed Viber on my Ubuntu. It works fine until I reboot the system. When I power off my laptop and turn on laptop again Viber does not connect to the internet even though I have internet connectivity generally. I have downloaded the official version of Viber from https://www.viber.com/en/download/. I downloaded the .deb file for Ubuntu. Also I get two Viber pop-ups when I reboot the system even though I have installed only one.


Details needed. There is no Ubuntu version info in your question. You say you downloaded Viber twice I bet you installed each of them, So 2 Viber is correct. Please edit the question and add the missing info.

Are you using Ubuntu 24.04?

This may be helpful for you https://askubuntu.com/a/1527954/1157209
